# Setting Global variable value on Button Click

Tags: android, global-variables, onclicklistener

I have a global parameter defined in my `MyApp` class which is used to reset some values in all activities and I want to set some default values for some `checkBoxes` and `SeekBars` but I am not able to call function `setDefaultvarValue` in `setOnclickListner()`.
Here is code for `myApp.class`:

```
class MyApp extends Application {

 private int setDefault=0;

 public int getDeafultVarValue() {
    return setDefault;
 }

public void setDefaultVarValue(int val) {
    setDefault = val;
 }
}
```

and `setonClickListner` looks like this :

```
 Button reset_btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    reset_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        ((MyApp) this.getApplication()).setDefaultVarValue(1);


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a different Activity?

Comment: Do you want to persist the setDefault? By persist I mean you want it to stay the same when the app is launched the next time?

Comment: @samgak I am trying it from in a fragment menu with is used to set some parameters i.e. min and max budget of a used laptop which a user can afford.

Comment: @Mooooooo no, It is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Call `setDefaultVarValue` method as from `MyApp` class :

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
   MyApp objMyApp = (MyApp)v.getContext().getApplicationContext();   
   objMyApp.setDefaultVarValue(1);      
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, tt's working very well but how can I call `getDefaultValue()` in a function which doesn't have a parameter `View v` i.e. in a class that looks like this `public AndroidSeekBar(SeekBar id1, TextView textid,int type)`{
...
}

Comment: @SahilSolanki : In `AndroidSeekBar` method use `textid` instead of `v` to call `getDefaultValue()` method

Answer (score 1):

please change your code to this.

```
Button reset_btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    reset_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ((MyApp)YourActivityname.this.getApplicationContext()).setDefaultVarValue(1);

        }
    });
```

If you are calling from the activity. Replace **YourActivityname** with your **Acitivity Name**. If you have any query please let me know.

Comment: Actually I am not using it in an activity but in a fragment method, which class is defined like this `public class BudgetFragment extends Fragment`

Answer (score 1):

When you `setDefaultVarValue` in `setOnClickListener` method, 
`setDefaultVarValue` is only called once in `setOnClickListener`

If you want `setDefaultVarValue` called when button clicked, you should move it inside `onClick` method

Answer (score 0):

Move this line `((MyApp) this.getApplication()).setDefaultVarValue(1);` inside `onClick()`

So it should be:

```
reset_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {       

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           ((MyApp) this.getApplication()).setDefaultVarValue(1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your setDefault method into the onClick method. Then everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Either try this: `((Activity) mContext).getApplication(...)` or make setDefaultVarValue method static It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. getter setter method helped me to declare my r variable and I'm able to control my variable within every function. Solution, even tho code looks ugly.

```
    private TextView broj;
    private TextView tekst1;
    private TextView posljednjeVrijeme;
    String stringTStamp;
    private int r;

    public int getDefaultR(){
        return r;
    }

    public void setDefaultR(int r){
        this.r=r;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                /**
                 * Ponavlja radnju svakih 4 sekunde, učitava vrijeme systema
                 */
                        final Handler ha=new Handler();
                        ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Long tStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                                stringTStamp = tStamp.toString();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stringTStamp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                SharedPreferences preferences3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences3.edit();
                                editor.putString("posljednjeVrijeme", stringTStamp);
                                editor.apply();



                                ha.postDelayed(this, 4000);
                            }
                        }, 4000);
                /**
                 * **************************************************************
                 */



        broj = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.broj);
        posljednjeVrijeme = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.posljednjeVrijeme);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final String name = preferences.getString("vrijednost je ", "");
        final String name2 = preferences.getString("posljednjeVrijeme", "");
        if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {

            broj.setText("vrijednost je "+name);
            posljednjeVrijeme.setText("Zadnje vrijeme "+name2);
        }



        Long tStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        stringTStamp = tStamp.toString();

        if(Integer.parseInt(stringTStamp)-Integer.parseInt(name2)<10){
            r = 0+Integer.parseInt(name);
            broj.setText("vrijednost je "+r);
        }

        else if(Integer.parseInt(stringTStamp)-Integer.parseInt(name2)>10){
            Toast.makeText(this, "POZDRAV GAZDA DUGO SE NE VIDJEH, UGASIO SI ME PRIJE " + (Integer.parseInt(stringTStamp)-Integer.parseInt(name2))+ " SEKUNDI" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            r = 0+Integer.parseInt(name)-10;
            broj.setText("vrijednost je "+r);

        }else{}





        tekst1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst1);
        final SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            tekst1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    r = r+1;


                    broj.setText("vrijednost je "+r);

                    String s= String.valueOf(r);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences2.edit();
                    editor.putString("vrijednost je ", s);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            });

    }
}
```